# JavaScript variable inside nested scope doesn't get error outside of scope

Tags: javascript

I cannot guess why this happen in below code:

```
(function(){
    console.log(`v1: `,v1); // show "undefined"
    console.log(`v2: `,v2); // show "Uncaught ReferenceError: v2 is not defined"

    if (true) {
        var v1 = 'something';
    }
})();
```

Why `v1` shows `undefined`? In the event that must like `v2` because `v1` define inside `if` block.

Comment: Thats why `let` & `const` were introduced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `var` to declare variables hoists their definition to the top of the function scope. Thus `v1` is declared but not defined (you define `v1` under the `if`). `v2` isn't declared in the function scope hence the different error.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of [`Hoisting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). The declaration of `v1` happens first, then the assignment.

Your code actually interpreted as:

```js
(function(){
    var v1;
    console.log(`v1: `,v1); // show "undefined"
    console.log(`v2: `,v2); // show "Uncaught ReferenceError: v2 is not defined"

    if (true) {
        v1 = 'something';
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is known as [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

> Conceptually, for example, a strict definition of hoisting suggests that variable and function declarations are physically moved to the top of your code, but this is not in fact what happens. Instead, the variable and function declarations are put into memory during the compile phase, but stay exactly where you typed them in your coding.
>
> JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations. If a variable is declared and initialized after using it, the value will be undefined